# Check if table row is visible on Apple Watch App

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have an app where I have to check whether the first row of the table is visible. I know how to do that on iOS but I need it in watch OS.

Answer (score 0):

The header file provides available options for watchOS tables, nothing there to check if a row is visible, file a radar if this is an important feature you would like:

```
@available(watchOS 2.0, *)
public class WKInterfaceTable : WKInterfaceObject {


public func setRowTypes(_ rowTypes: [String]) // row names. size of array is number of rows

public func setNumberOfRows(_ numberOfRows: Int, withRowType rowType: String) // repeating row name


public var numberOfRows: Int { get }

public func rowController(at index: Int) -> AnyObject?


public func insertRows(at rows: IndexSet, withRowType rowType: String)

public func removeRows(at rows: IndexSet)


public func scrollToRow(at index: Int)


@available(watchOS 3.0, *)
public func performSegue(forRow row: Int)
}
```